# Enumerar consulta en MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estoy tratando de realizar una consulta MySQL desde CodeIgniter, y la query va bien pero me gustaría agregar un campo dentro del select que cuente los registros que me devuelve la consulta.

```sql
SELECT r.fecha_inicio, r.fecha_fin, c.Nombre as cliente FROM reserva r, cliente c WHERE c.Id_cliente = r.Id_cliente AND r.Id_producto = @parametro
```

Esa es mi consulta simple, ¿Cómo podría agregar ese campo más en el select?

consulta final

```html
SELECT @i := @i + 1 as contador, r.fecha_inicio, r.fecha_fin, c.Nombre as Cliente 
FROM reserva r 
CROSS JOIN (select @i := 0) r
INNER JOIN cliente c 
ON r.Id_cliente = c.Id_cliente 
WHERE r.Id_espacio = @parametro
```

Comment: Perdon... pero la idea es: ¿que te devuelva la totalidad de los registro del select?...  o que ademas de la información proporcionada... aparezca la cuenta (lo cual te mostraría una repiticion del mismo dato ).

Comment: solo que me enumere cada registro, si la consulta me devuelve 6 registros, quiero un campo en cada registro desde el 1 hasta el 6

Comment: `SET @i = 0; SELECT (@i := @i + 1) AS contador, r.fecha_inicio, r.fecha_fin, c.Nombre as cliente FROM reserva r, cliente c WHERE c.Id_cliente = r.Id_cliente AND r.Id_producto = @parametro`

Comment: e intentado esto, pero lo estoy asiendo desde php y tengo problemas a la hora de pasar las variables del contador

Comment: ¿Cuáles variables del contador? El contador no necesita ninguna variable, o lo inicias a cero con SET o creas la consulta como se indica en la respuesta A, el contador se incrementa sólo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias formas de poder hacerlo:

### A. Con una sola consulta

```
SELECT @i := @i + 1 as contador, r.fecha_inicio, r.fecha_fin, c.Nombre as cliente 
FROM reserva r, cliente c 
cross join (select @i := 0) r
WHERE c.Id_cliente = r.Id_cliente AND r.Id_producto = @parametro
```

Esta parte: `cross join (select @i := 0) r`  permite inicializar el contador sin tener que usar SET.

### B. Con dos consultas

```
SET @i = 0; 

SELECT (@i := @i + 1) AS contador, r.fecha_inicio, r.fecha_fin, c.Nombre as cliente 
FROM reserva r, cliente c 
WHERE c.Id_cliente = r.Id_cliente AND r.Id_producto = @parametro
```

**Nota**

Es recomendable usar JOIN en vez de WHERE para unir las tablas. Me refiero a cambiar esto:
`WHERE c.Id_cliente = r.Id_cliente AND r.Id_producto = @parametro`
por un JOIN que una las tablas `c` y `r`, ya que es más eficaz que WHERE.

---

### EDIT: EJEMPLO COMPLETO USANDO JOIN EN VEZ DE WHERE

Como se puede ver en la **Query 2**, se usa: `INNER JOIN cliente c ON r.id_cliente=c.id_cliente` para unir las tablas, porque es mucho más eficaz que usar WHERE.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b1313/3)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE cliente
    (`id_cliente` int, `cliente_nom` varchar(70))
;
    
INSERT INTO cliente
    (`id_cliente`, `cliente_nom`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Pedro'),
    (2, 'Santiago'),
    (3, 'Juan')
;

CREATE TABLE reserva
    (`id_reserva` int, `id_cliente` int, `fecha` date, `id_producto` int)
;
    
INSERT INTO reserva
    (`id_reserva`, `id_cliente`, `fecha`, `id_producto`)
VALUES
    (1, 1,'2017-05-01', 1),
    (2, 2,'2017-05-05', 1),
    (3, 3,'2017-05-11', 1),
    (4, 1,'2017-05-14', 1),
    (5, 1,'2017-05-17', 2),
    (6, 2,'2017-05-20', 2)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SET @parametro=1;
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT 
  @i := @i + 1 as contador, 
  r.fecha,
  c.cliente_nom,
  r.id_producto
FROM reserva r
INNER JOIN cliente c ON r.id_cliente=c.id_cliente
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @i := 0) r
WHERE r.id_producto = @parametro
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b1313/3/1)**:

```
| contador |                 fecha | cliente_nom | id_producto |
|----------|-----------------------|-------------|-------------|
|        1 | May, 01 2017 00:00:00 |       Pedro |           1 |
|        2 | May, 05 2017 00:00:00 |    Santiago |           1 |
|        3 | May, 11 2017 00:00:00 |        Juan |           1 |
|        4 | May, 14 2017 00:00:00 |       Pedro |           1 |
```

Comment: tengo un error en el cross join, pero muchas gracias por el consejo ahora lo modifico con un join en lugar del where.

Comment: Ponlo después del WHERE ... en realidad nunca uno dos tablas con WHERE, sino con INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, etc, según el caso.

Comment: muchas gracias, edite mi pregunta asi talvez para alquien sea de utilidad la respuesta.

Comment: @max me alegro. Al final te puse un fiddle con un ejemplo usando JOIN para unir las tablas. Considera dar un voto positivo a la(s) respuesta(s) usando la flecha gris que apunta hacia arriba. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Para MySQL

```
SELECT @n := @n + 1 n,
       first_name, 
       last_name
  FROM table1, (SELECT @n := 0) m
 ORDER BY first_name, last_name
```

creo que para tu caso quedaría así:

```
    SELECT @n := @n + 1 n, r.fecha_inicio, r.fecha_fin, c.Nombre as cliente 
FROM reserva r, (SELECT @n := 0) n, cliente c 
WHERE c.Id_cliente = r.Id_cliente AND r.Id_producto = @parametro
```

Lo saqué de esta otra pregunta: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16555454/how-to-generate-auto-increment-field-in-select-query

Comment: tengo un error de sintaxis justo en el select del FROM